# Is there an easier way to calculate the partial derivative?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> If $$w=z\tan^{-1}\Big(\frac{x}{y}\Big),$$
>
> find$$\frac{\partial^2 {w}}{\partial{x^2}}+\frac{\partial^2
>  {w}}{\partial{y^2}}+\frac{\partial^2 {w}}{\partial{z^2}}=?$$

I calculated this and the answer is zero. But It was long calculations ( find $\frac{\partial {w}}{\partial{x}}$ then calculate $\frac{\partial^2 {w}}{\partial{x^2}}$ and do this again for $y$ and $z$ ):
\begin{align} 
\frac{\partial {w}}{\partial{x}}&=\frac{yz}{x^2+y^2}\\
\frac{\partial^2 {w}}{\partial{x^2}}&=\frac{2xyz}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\\
\frac{\partial {w}}{\partial{y}}&=\frac{-zx}{x^2+y^2}\\
\frac{\partial^2 {w}}{\partial{y^2}}&=\frac{-2xyz}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\\
\frac{\partial^2 {w}}{\partial{z^2}}&=0. 
\end{align}

I wonder if there is a shorter answer or another approach to calculate this? (Because the answer is zero I guess maybe there is different approach too.)

Comment: it is obvious that $\frac{\partial^2 {w}}{\partial{z^2}}$ is zero, maybe the other two are easier to see after the first derivative, write out the details in the post

Comment: Ok, I edited this

Comment: Maybe recast the Laplacian in cylindrical coordinates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second derivative with respect to $z$ is clearly zero. Furthermore, $$\arctan(y/x) = \operatorname{Im}(\operatorname{Log}(x + \mathrm iy))$$ and we know that the imaginary part of an analytic function is harmonic (satisfies Laplace's equation). The result for $\arctan(x/y)$ follows by symmetry.

Comment: How we know: $\arctan(y/x) = \operatorname{Im}(\operatorname{Log}(z))$?

Comment: Maybe better write $\operatorname{Log}(x+iy)$ since the variable name $z$ is already in use.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my answer. @Soheil See the definition of the complex logarithm, especially the principal value: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm

Comment: @Jan Ok I saw the proof here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260028/find-the-real-and-imaginary-parts-of-lnz       But still have a question: How we should recognize a function is imaginary part of an analytic function like this? should Memorize them?

Comment: See for example here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48980/finding-an-analytic-function-given-the-real-imaginary-part It is of course also helpful if you know some definitions or memorize some common functions.